# How to inherit a flask MethodView class without its decorators?

Tags: python, api, inheritance, flask, decorator

For the reason of not rewriting the same API. I want to inherit a get method from an already created `MethodView` and **ignore** the `login_required` **decorator**.

```
class DoStuffA(MethodView):
    decorators = [login_required]
    def get(self):
        return jsonify({"status":"ok"})

api.add_url_rule('/dostufa', view_func=DoStuffA.as_view("dostuffa"), methods=['GET'])

class DoStuffB(DoStuffA):
    pass

api.add_url_rule('/dostuffb', view_func=DoStuffB.as_view("dostuffb"), methods=['GET'])
```

If I do a GET request to `/dostuffb`,

1. Does it need to be authenticated?
2. Is my inheritance syntax correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View.decorators` list is applied only when the `View.as_view()` method is called. If you don't want any decorators to be applied in your subclass, just override the attribute with an empty sequence:

```
class DoStuffB(DoStuffA):
    decorators = ()  # empty tuple
```

Now `DoStuffB.as_view()` will find the empty tuple rather than the inherited `DoStuffA.decorators` list, and no decorators are applied.