# how to set up an Inherited MethodView in Flask to do CRUD operations on sqlalchemy models

Tags: python, inheritance, flask, sqlalchemy, crud

In order to avoid writing api methodviews for my models. i wish to create a more elegant inherited way of doing this.

```
class ModelCrudAPI(MethodView):

    def __init__(self, model):
      self.model = model

    def get(self):
        store_id = request.args.get("store_id", None, int)
        waiters = self.model.query.filter_by(store_id=store_id).all()

        if waiters is None or store_id is None:
            return jsonify({'items': [], 'store_id': store_id}), 204

        # TODO: change personnel_data to list
        else:
            items = []
            for waiter in waiters:
                items.append(row2dict(waiter))
            return jsonify({"items": items, 'store_id': store_id})
```

I have set up a similar Inheritance in this question before.
[previous question about inheritance and decorators in methodviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652544/how-to-inherit-a-flask-methodview-class-without-its-decorators)

Notice i want to pass in an sqlalcdhemy model to my class.

**First Scenario**

```
class Test(ModelCrudAPI):

    def __init__(self, model):
        super(Test, self).__init__(model)

api.add_url_rule("/test", view_func=Test(MYMODEL).as_view("test"), methods=['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'])
```

ERROR:

```
flask debuger :TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**Second Scenario** )

```
class Test(ModelCrudAPI):

    def __init__(self, MYMODEL):
        super(Test, self).__init__(MYMODEL)

api.add_url_rule("/test", view_func=Test.as_view("test"), methods=['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'])
```

ERROR:

```
flask debuger :TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

i would really apreciate any help. this will clean up my code.

**EDIT THIS WORKS**

```
class Test(ModelCrudAPI):
    def __init__(self):
        ModelCrudAPI.__init__(self, Personnel)


api.add_url_rule("/test", view_func=Test.as_view("test"), methods=['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'])
```

Answer (score 3):

[`as_view`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.views.View.as_view) is a *`classmethod`*, and it forwards arguments provided to it to the class' constructor.  So all you have to do is pass your model as the *second* argument to `as_view`:

```
class Test(ModelCrudAPI):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(Test, self).__init__(model)

api.add_url_rule("/test", view_func=Test.as_view("test", MYMODEL), methods=['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'])
```